# helper function overwriting previous values in mapped list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I have a mapped list of applicants, each of which contain a finalStatus property. This mapped list renders a component with a custom dropdown and takes the applicant as a prop.

I have data file with a dropdown object that I pull in to the component to render a dropdown.

Each of these has a disabled property true or false which is initially set to false like so...

```
    complianceStatus: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'None', disabled: false },
        {id: 2,  value: 'Provisionally', disabled: false},
        {id: 3,  value: 'Fully', disabled: false },
    ],
```

then when the component mounts i run a useEffect to get the dropdown data and perform a helper function on it in order to determine whether or not disabled should be true or false based on a value from the applicant object. I then set this object to state to render the dropdown.

this is the use effect

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setDropdownData(utils.getDropdownData('complianceStatus', applicant));
    }, [applicant]);
```

For reference my util function are here

```
export const getDropdownData = (type, applicant) => {
            const optionData = mergeArray(data.dropdownData[type], type, applicant);
        return optionData;
    }


const mergeArray = (dropDownData, type, data) => {
    if (type === 'actionList') {
        mergeArrayActionListHelper(dropDownData, data);
    }
    if (type === 'complianceStatus') {
        disableComplianceStatus(dropDownData, data);
    }

    return dropDownData;
}


export const disableComplianceStatus = (dropdownData, applicant) => {
   
    switch(applicant.finalStatus) {
        case 'fully_compliant':
            dropdownData[0].disabled = true;
            dropdownData[1].disabled = true;
            dropdownData[2].disabled = true;
            return;
        case 'partially_compliant':
            dropdownData[0].disabled = true;
            dropdownData[1].disabled = true;
            dropdownData[2].disabled = false;
            return;
        default:
            dropdownData[0].disabled = true;
            dropdownData[1].disabled = false;
            dropdownData[2].disabled = false;
            return;


    }

}
```

My list of dropdown's is rendering but with a strange quirk.

The problem is, the last applicant in the list seems to overwrite the disabled property of all previous applicants.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

EDIT FOR SOME MORE INFO ON APPLICANT

The applicant is a large object several components up. It is for a table style dashboard where each applicant has a row.

it is first passed to DashboardRow component where there is no state being set.

```
return (
        <div className='dashboard-row'>
            {
                staticDash ? (
                    <DashboardRowStatic applicant={applicant}/>
                ) : (
                    <DashboardRowDynamic 
                        applicant={applicant} 
                      
                    />
                )

            }
        </div>
    )
```

This then renders the actual items on the rows and the component looks like this

```
const DashboardRowDynamic = ({applicant, applicantNumber, applicantLength}) => {
    const dynamicTableData = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.dynamicTableData);

    return (
        dynamicTableData && dynamicTableData.length > 0 && 
        <div className='dashboard-row-dynamic'>
            {
                dynamicTableData[1].values.map(value => {
                    if (value === 'finalStatus') {
                        return (
                            <div key={value} className='col-md center'>
                                <ProfileFinalStatus 
                                    applicantFromDash={applicant} 
                                    applicantNumber={applicantNumber} 
                                    applicantLength={applicantLength} 
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    } 
         
                    else if (value === 'suspendedMessage') {
                        return (
                            <div key={value} className='col-md'>
                                <TooltipLg title={applicant[value]}>
                                    <p className='orka-semi-p tooltip'>{applicant[value]}</p>
                                </TooltipLg>
                            </div>
                        )
                        
                    } else {
                        return (
                            <div key={value} className='col-md'>
                                <p className='orka-semi-p'>{applicant[value]}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    } 
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then for reference this is the entire FinalStatus component

```
const ProfileFinalStatus = ({applicantFromDash, applicantNumber = 0, applicantLength = 20}) => {

    const applicant = useSelector(state => state.profile.applicant);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [dropdownData, setDropdownData] = useState([]);
    const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState(null);
    const [localApplicant, setLocalApplicant] = useState(null);

   
    useEffect(() => {
        const applicantSelect = applicantFromDash ? applicantFromDash : applicant;
        setLocalApplicant(applicantSelect);
        setDropdownData(utils.getDropdownData('complianceStatus', applicantSelect));
    }, [applicant, applicantFromDash]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localApplicant) {
            const data = dropdownData.filter(item => {
                return item.dbValue === localApplicant.finalStatus;
            });

            getIcon(data);           
            setDefaultData(data[0]);
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [JSON.stringify(dropdownData), JSON.stringify(localApplicant)]);



    const getIcon = (data) => {
        switch(data[0].dbValue) {
            case 'partially_compliant':
                data[0].icon = partially;
                return;
            case 'fully_compliant':
                data[0].icon = fully;
                return;
            default:
                data[0].icon = none;
                return;
        }
    }


    const getDropdownVal = (val) => {
        const payload = {
            finalStatus: val.dbValue
        }

        apiApplicant.updateApplicant(localApplicant.workerUuid, payload)
        .then(res => {
            const data = dropdownData.filter(item => {
                return item.dbValue === payload.finalStatus;
            });
            localApplicant.finalStatus = val.dbValue;
            setDropdownData(utils.getDropdownData('complianceStatus', localApplicant));
           
            setDefaultData(data[0]);
            if (applicantFromDash) {
                dispatch(refetchApplicants());
            }
            dispatch(setAlert({
                type: 'success',
                message: 'Successfully updated compliance status',
                isVisible: true
            }));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(setAlert({
                type: 'error',
                message: 'Error updating face to face status',
                isVisible: true
            }));
        })

    }

    const getPosition = () => {
        let position;
        // applicantLength = 2;
        // if (applicantLength === 2) {
        //     position = 'top-center';
        // } else {
            position = applicantNumber > 16 ? 'top-center' : 'bottom-center';
        // }
        // console.log(applicantLength)
        // console.log(position)

        return position;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {
                defaultData &&
                (
                    <Dropdown 
                        type="complianceStatus" 
                        dropdownData={dropdownData}
                        defaultData={defaultData} 
                        getDropdownVal={getDropdownVal} 
                        width="160"
                        height='24'
                        mobileResponsive={false}
                        position={getPosition()}

                    />
                )
            }
            
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProfileFinalStatus;
```

EDIT 2
dropdownData is in a file data.js

```
export const dropdownData = {
    searchBy: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'First Name', dbValue: 'name', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 2,  value: 'Surname', dbValue: 'surname', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 3,  value: 'Email', dbValue: 'email', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 4,  value: 'NI Number', dbValue: 'nationalInsuranceNumber', class: "dropdown-grey"}
    ],
    sortBy: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'Urgent', dbValue: 'urgent', sortAsc: false, class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 2,  value: 'Name', dbValue: 'name', sortAsc: false, class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 3,  value: 'Email', dbValue: 'email', sortAsc: false, class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 4,  value: 'Created Date', dbValue: 'created_at', sortAsc: false, class: "dropdown-grey"}
    ],
    submissionStatus: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'Pending', dbValue: 'pending', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 2,  value: 'Accepted', dbValue: 'accepted', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 3,  value: 'Rejected', dbValue: 'rejected', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 4,  value: 'Unsuccessful', dbValue: 'unsuccessful', class: "dropdown-grey"}
    ],
    complianceStatus: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'None', dbValue: 'not_compliant', class: "dropdown-grey", disabled: false },
        {id: 2,  value: 'Provisionally', dbValue: 'partially_compliant', class: "dropdown-yellow", disabled: false},
        {id: 3,  value: 'Fully', dbValue: 'fully_compliant', class: "dropdown-green", disabled: false },
    ],
    actionList: [
        {id: 1,  value: 'Suspended', openModal: true, isSuspended: false },
        {id: 2,  value: 'Mark Urgent', openModal: false, isUrgent: false },
        {id: 3,  value: 'Edit User', openModal: true },
        {id: 4,  value: 'CV Online', openModal: false },
        {id: 5,  value: 'Identity Check', openModal: true },
    ],
    employmentTypes: [
        {id: 1,  dbValue: 'employed', value: 'Employed', fullView: true, class: 'blue-outline' },
        {id: 2,  dbValue: 'self-employed', value: 'Self Employed', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'   },
        {id: 3,  dbValue: 'studying', value: 'Studying', fullView: true, class: 'blue-outline'   },
        {id: 4,  dbValue: 'carer', value: 'Carer', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 5,  dbValue: 'redundant', value: 'Redundant', fullView: true, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 6,  dbValue: 'sick', value: 'Sick', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 7,  dbValue: 'travelling', value: 'Travelling', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 8,  dbValue: 'volunteering', value: 'Volunteering', fullView: true, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 9,  dbValue: 'unemployed-claiming', value: 'Unemployed Claiming', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'  },
        {id: 10,  dbValue: 'unemployed-not-claiming', value: 'Unemployed Not Claiming', fullView: false, class: 'blue-outline'  },
    ],
    faceToFaceActions: [
        {id: 1, value: 'Pending', dbValue: 'pending', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 2, value: 'Approve', dbValue: 'passed', class: "dropdown-grey"},
        {id: 3, value: 'Reject', dbValue: 'failed', class: "dropdown-grey"}
    ]
}
```

there is then a utils functions file which imports data

```
import * as data from './data.js';
```

you can see the utils functions above.

then in the final status component utils is imported like this

```
import * as utils from '../../utils/utilsFunctions';
```

it is then called in the ProfileFinalStatus component as seen in the snippet above.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the applicant? Is there something looping somewhere setting state updates? Can you try to describe more the steps taken to reproduce the issue?

Comment: ive added some more info in the question if that helps. hopefully not overkill.

Comment: What is `data.dropdownData` in `getDropdownData`? You are definitely looping over a data structure and calling `getDropdownData` eventually, which appears to mutating the passed `data.dropdownData[type]` object.

Comment: thanks @DrewReese Ive added another edit to the main so you can see data.getDropdownData[type]. It is an array of objects.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for what the entire `data.dropdownData` was. Perhaps even `data` itself. If possible I'd like to see how it relates to the UI code and looping `dynamicTableData` array. In the snippets I don't see where `data` is declared or passed as an argument to the `getDropdownData` utility.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I've amended that edit. hopefully there is enough info there. Data is just a file data.js that contains various exports, one being dropdownData.

this is the line where the first function is called. 

setDropdownData(utils.getDropdownData('complianceStatus', applicantSelect));

*apologies i think the first line in the utility was missing before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227049/discussion-between-user10045300-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

I believe the issue is a `dropdownData` object mutation in the `disableComplianceStatus` utility.

The steps I think occur are:

1. `DashboardRowDynamic` renders an array of table data and renders a `ProfileFinalStatus` component.
2. `ProfileFinalStatus` populates its `dropdownData` state array by calling `setDropdownData(utils.getDropdownData('complianceStatus', applicantSelect));`.
3. `getDropdownData` passes `data.dropdownData[type]` as `dropdownData` to `mergeArray` and returns `mergeArray`'s return value.
4. `mergeArray` calls `disableComplianceStatus` and passes `dropdownData` and returns `dropdownData`.
5. `disableComplianceStatus` directly mutates the `dropdownData` object, setting the `disabled` property.

When this occurs in a loop, each iteration is mutating this same object as it is all still a reference back to the original object stored in the object exported from your `data.js` file. Each iterated item mutates the referenced object, and is mutating the object reference all previous elements have.

## Solution

At some point in this flow you just need to shallow copy the `dropdownData` object so each mapped element get their own copy of it to mutate. A good place for this IMO would be in the `disableComplianceStatus` utility. Instead of mutating the passed object it should copy, set properties, and return the new object. `mergeArray` should then return *that* new object instead of the passed `dropdownData` object.

I submit to you the following changes

1. `mergeArray` returns the result from the utilities it calls.

   ```
   const mergeArray = (dropDownData, type, data) => {
     if (type === 'actionList') {
       return mergeArrayActionListHelper(dropDownData, data);
     }
     if (type === 'complianceStatus') {
       return disableComplianceStatus(dropDownData, data);
     }

     return dropDownData;
   }
   ```
2. `disableComplianceStatus` shallow copies the `dropdownData` object *then* updates properties, returning the new object reference. These needs to be done at each level you are updating properties of, so this includes the array elements too.

***Note:** You will need to apply a similar fix to `mergeArrayActionListHelper` utility.*

```
    export const disableComplianceStatus = (dropdownData, applicant) => {
      let disabled = [];

      switch(applicant.finalStatus) {
        case 'fully_compliant':
          disabled = [true, true, true];
          break;
        case 'partially_compliant':
          disabled = [true, true, false];
          break;
        default:
          disabled = [true, false, false];
          break;
      }

      // return new mapped array with copies of all elements.
      return dropdownData.map((el, i) => ({
        ...el,
        disabled: !!disabled[i],
      }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Drew that was absolutely this issue!